# HDMI and DVI cable

Tags: hdmi, cable, pin

I have bought a cable: one end is DVI and the other is HDMI. This DVI cable has  3x3 plus 3x3 pins with a space
between these 2 groups.
But the PC end has 8x3 pins. Can I insert the cable into the PC safely ?
I haven't unpacked the cable: I will wait until someone answers my Q.
[This](https://www.tsbohemia.cz/kb-kabel-hdmi-a-dvi-d-m-m-1-8m_d59440.html?fulltextword=9734412) is the cable. I need to connect a TV to my PC to detect why there are imperfections on my LCD display.

[image]

Comment: Those cables typically are uni-directional.  Be sure you connect it per the specification and instructions of the cable manufacture.

Comment: @Ramhound I was under the impression that DVI and HDMI were electrically identical, just with different connectors. Shouldn't that mean that they are bi-directional?

Comment: @SamForbis - HDMI supports video and audio, DVI supports video, they most definitely are not electrically identically.  There is a reason I indicate to follow the instructions of the manufacture (as I was unable to verify if the author's cable is indeed bi-directional).

Comment: I have tried it and it works. Sound goes from my OLD repros. Now I will wait till the imperfections appear on my PC LCD to see it on TV (or not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the picture provided, we can tell that the cable you purchased is a DVI-D (Single-Link):

[image]

By '8*3', you most probably mean DVI (Dual-Link)

If your PC's DVI input looks like this:

[image]

or this:

[image]

You should be good to go.

There is another post on this subject if you would like to know more [here](https://superuser.com/questions/440159/can-a-single-link-dvi-cable-be-connected-to-a-dual-link-dvi-port/440172#:%7E:text=Yes%2C%20a%20dual%20link%20port,single%20and%20dual%20link%20cables.&text=Yes%20you%20can%20connect%20a,port%20but%20not%20the%20opposite.&text=Your%20computer%20DVI%2DI%20output,and%20a%20DVI%2DI%20connector.):

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your PC has a dual-link DVI port (the "8x3" you mentioned). As long as that is the case, it is compatible with any other DVI cable, as long as you don't try to insert a DVI-I cable into a DVI-D port. As far as I know, DVI-I went the way of the dinosaur along with analog displays, so you likely have a DVI-D dual-link port on your PC and the cable you linked is DVI-D single-link. You're good to go. Here's a reference image for you.

[image]